# Mobile Hybrid application Facebook and Twitter plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, cordova

Is there any Hybrid mobile app plugin for Facebook and Twitter. Please point me to realtime examples and detailed usage of the plugins in javascript.

or

Should this be handled from native app, but using cordova to communicate. Please post the supportive links and implementation examples.

Requirements are:

- Need to login to Facebook/Twitter
- Post images and text on the logged in user wall from the hybrid mobile application

Hybrid app:

- Jquery 1.10.2
- Jquery mobile 1.3.2
- Cordova 2.5.0

Target Platforms: ALL